# Need to reinstall urllib2 for Python 2.7

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, debian

I need to reinstall the **urllib2.py** for my **Python2.7** installation on Ubuntu because it's corrupted, I allready did

> aptitude reinstall python2.7

to get the original file back but only this certain files is still broken (because I changed some code in it xD). What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dpkg -S` to search for the files you need re-installed:

```
$ dpkg -S urllib2.py
libpython2.7-stdlib:amd64: /usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py
```

I ran the command on an Ubuntu 16.04 system with Python 2 installed, and there I'd have to reinstall `libpython2.7-stdlib` to get that file:

```
$ sudo aptitude reinstall libpython2.7-stdlib
```

The alternative is to get the package and extract individual files by hand:

```
$ package = libpython2.7-stdlib
$ mkdir $package
$ cd $package
$ apt-get download $package  # fetch the .deb file
$ ar vx ${package}*.deb      # extract metadata and data.tar.xz
$ tar xJvf data.tar.xz ./usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py
$ sudo mv usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py /usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py
```